# Ненормативное употребление частей речи

Tags: значение-слов

Исправить ошибки, связанные с ненормативным употреблением частей речи:

1. Герои Островского горячи, полны жизни.
2. Когда я выздоровлю, то одену пальто и шапку, пойду гулять на улицу.
3. Хозяйка сняла со стола чемодан и отодвинула его в сторону.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Герои Островского горячи, полны жизни.

Не вижу здесь ошибок.

2) Когда я выздоров**ею**, то **на**дену пальто и шапку, пойду гулять на улицу.

3) Хозяйка сняла со стола чемодан и отодвинула его в сторону.

Здесь, видимо, имелось в виду, что хозяйка передвинула стол, но выходит, что она передвинула чемодан.

Answer (score 2):

1) Герои Островского горячие, полные жизни.
При употреблении прилагательных в переносном значении краткая форма 
обычно не используется.Полные формы  обозначают постоянный признак, вневременное качество, а краткие – временный признак, недлительное состояние:горячий парень - суп горяч.

В остальном согласна с  Сергеем:

2) Когда я выздоровЕЮ, то НАдену пальто и шапку, пойду гулять на улицу.

3) Хозяйка сняла со стола чемодан и отодвинула стол в сторону.Местоимение нельзя употреблять из-за двусмысленности.

Answer (score 0):

Хозяйка сняла со стола чемодан и отодвинула его в сторону.(Чтобы не возникало двусмысленности по поводу того, ЧТО хозяйка отодвинула в сторону, следует построить предложение так: "Хозяйка сняла чемодан со стола  и отодвинула его в сторону", так как местоимение  заменяет собой ближайшее предшествующее существительное, которым является слово "стол"

Comment: почему Вы решили, что она отодвинула стол?

Answer (score 0):

Герои Островского горячи, полны жизни.
Когда я выздоровею, надену пальто,шапку и пойду гулять на улицу.
Хозяйка сняла со стола чемодан,отодвинув его в сторону.